# Rare ruby segfault within nested enumeration

Tags: ruby, segmentation-fault

Every 3000 executions or so, I get a segfault in the following code, on the `y << v` line.

`cache` is a string->object hash, and enum_files is a helper method to make filtered access easier.

```
  def enum_files
    load_all
    Enumerator.new  do |y| 
      cache.each do |k,v|      
        y << v if yield(v)
      end
    end
  end

  def pages
    @cached_pages ||= enum_files { |p| p.is_page? && p.can_render? }.to_a
  end

  def posts
    @cached_posts ||= enum_files { |p| p.is_page? && p.can_render? && p.is_post? }.sort { |x, y| y.date <=> x.date }
  end
```

(full source at http://hardwiredcms.com)

I'm running `ruby 1.9.3p362` on `OS X 10.8.2 [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]`

[Here's the full error stack](https://gist.github.com/4686226)  (no information was written to Console or CrashReporter, unfortunately)

#### Am I doing something stupid?